# BadDataError when editing a .dbf file using dbf package

Tags: python-2.7, dbf, dbase

I have recently produced several thousand shapefile outputs and accompanying .dbf files from an atmospheric model (HYSPLIT) on a unix system. The converter `txt2dbf` is used to convert shapefile attribute tables (text file) to a .dbf.

Unfortunately, something has gone wrong (probably a separator/field length error) because there are 2 problems with the output .dbf files, as follows:

1. Some fields of the dbf contain data that should not be there. This data has "spilled over" from neighbouring fields.
2. An additional field has been added that should not be there (it actually comes from a section of the first record of the text file, "1000 201").

This is an example of the first record in the output dbf (retrieved using `dbview` unix package):

> Trajnum    : 1001 2
> Yyyymmdd   : 0111231 2
> Time       : 300
> Level      : 0.
> 1000 201:

Here's what I expected:

> Trajnum    : 1000
> Yyyymmdd   : 20111231
> Time       : 2300
> Level      : 0.

Separately, I'm looking at how to prevent this from happening again, but ideally I'd like to be able to repair the existing .dbf files. Unfortunately the text files are removed for each model run, so "fixing" the .dbf files is the only option.

My approaches to the above problems are:

1. Extract the information from the fields that do exist to a new variable using `dbf.add_fields` and `dbf.write` (python package `dbf`), then delete the old incorrect fields using `dbf.delete_fields`.
2. Delete the unwanted additional field.

This is what I've tried:

```
        with dbf.Table(db) as db:
            db.add_fields("TRAJNUMc C(4)") #create new fields
            db.add_fields("YYYYMMDDc C(8)")
            db.add_fields("TIMEc C(4)")
            for record in db: #extract data from fields
                    dbf.write(TRAJNUMc=int(str(record.Trajnum)[:4]))
                    dbf.write(YYYYMMDDc=int(str(record.Trajnum)[-1:] + str(record.Yyyymmdd)[:7]))
                    dbf.write(TIMEc=record.Yyyymmdd[-1:] + record.Time[:])
            db.delete_fields('Trajnum') # delete the incorrect fields
            db.delete_fields('Yyyymmdd')
            db.delete_fields('Time')
            db.delete_fields('1000 201') #delete the unwanted field
            db.pack()
```

But this produces the following error:

```
dbf.ver_2.BadDataError: record data is not the correct length (should be 31, not 30)
```

Given the apparent problem that there has been with the `txt2dbf` conversion, I'm not surprised to find an error in the record data length. However, does this mean that the file is completely corrupted and that I can't extract the information that I need (frustrating because I can see that it exists)?

---

## EDIT:

Rather than attempting to edit the 'bad' .dbf files, it seems a better approach to 1. extract the required data to a text from the bad files and then 2. write to a new dbf. (See Ethan Furman's comments/answer below).

---

## EDIT:

An example of a faulty .dbf file that I need to fix/recover data from can be found here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9y92f7m88a8g5y4/p0001120110.dbf?dl=0

An example .txt file from which the faulty dbf files were created can be found here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/d0f2c0zehsyy8ab/attTEST.txt?dl=0

Comment: Seems like it might be easier to reconstruct the text file from the dbf file and then reconvert -- have you tried?

Comment: Thanks, Ethan. No I hadn't thought to try this.. seems like it could be a get-out-of-jail card.. Would this be a case of reversing the `txt2dbf` command that I used `txt2dbf -C7 -C9 -C5 -C9 -d, -d, -d, file.att file.dbf` to `dbf2txt -C7 -C9 -C5 -C9 -d, -d, -d, file.dbf file.att`

Comment: I haven't used those commands so I don't know.  It may take some extra care as a C9 field, for example, will have 9 characters, even if the last few are just spaces.  Depending on what your input file looked like, this may be fine -- perhaps you could post a few example lines of an input text file?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/d0f2c0zehsyy8ab/attTEST.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the data and recreate the original text file, this snippet should help:

```
import dbf

table = dbf.Table('/path/to/scramble/table.dbf')
with table:
    fixed_data = []
    for record in table:
        # convert to str/bytes while skipping delete flag
        data = record._data[1:].tostring()
        trajnum = data[:4]
        ymd = data[4:12]
        time = data [12:16]
        level = data[16:].strip()
        fixed_data.extend([trajnum, ymd, time, level])

new_file = open('repaired_data.txt', 'w')
for line in fixed_data:
    new_file.write(','.join(line) + '\n')
```

Assuming all your data files look like your sample (the big *IF* being the data has no embedded commas), then this rough code should help translate your text files into dbfs:

```
raw_data = open('some_text_file.txt').read().split('\n')
final_table = dbf.Table(
        'dest_table.dbf',
        'trajnum C(4); yyyymmdd C(8); time C(4); level C(9)',
        )
with final_table:
    for line in raw_data:
        fields = line.split(',')
        final_table.append(tuple(fields))

# table has been populated and closed
```

Of course, you could get fancier and use actual date, and number fields if you want to:

```
# dbf string becomes
'trajnum N; yyyymmdd D; time C(4), level N'

#appending data loop becomes
    for line in raw_data:
        trajnum, ymd, time, level = line.split(',')
        trajnum = int(trajnum)
        ymd = dbf.Date(ymd[:4], ymd[4:6], ymd[6:])
        level = int(level)
        final_table.append((trajnum, ymd, time, level))
```

Comment: This seems really promising - thanks for the code above. I've tried to run the first block of code to recover the original text but I get the error `AttributeError: 'array.array' object has no attribute 'strip'` when `data[16:].strip()` is used or the familiar error `dbf.ver_2.BadDataError: record data is not the correct length (should be 31, not 30)` when I # out the .strip() part.

Comment: (Seperately,) I've also tried to run the second block of code on the example text file, but I get the following error: `dbf.ver_2.DbfError: incoming data has too many values`.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that.  Updated snippets.

Comment: The first snippet is now just about working - I can produce a text file with each line like this: _1001,20120109,2300,       7._. The problem is that the first record is missing, so the text file doesn't begin at _1000,20120110,0000..._.

Comment: The 2nd snippet to convert the recovered .txt to a .dbf seems to be working nicely (thanks!) - but the 1st record loss from the first snippet is propagating through to the final dbf (as you'd expect).

Comment: I guess the problem may be that in the initial "broken" .dbf table, the first record isn't being separated from the line containing the header text (an example of the initial "broken" .dbf table can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9y92f7m88a8g5y4/p0001120110.dbf?dl=0).

Comment: @MattJones:  Yeah, it looks like that first line was lost in the initial conversion process, so you aren't going to be able to get it back.

Comment: Thanks for your help. As a final step I'll try to add that first record in manually